# Search and replace string in unix bash regex

Tags: bash, replace

Does anyone have an idea on how to search and replace in a string? Let's say for example I have a string

```
string=".blah http://google.com.ph/tabs/1.5.8 setup https://yahoo.com.ph/root/blah"
```

I want to search for version `1.5.8` and then replace it with `1.5.9`. How do i do it in bash?

Answer (score 3):

```
instring="version 1.5.8"
outstring=${instring//1.5.8/1.5.9}
```

Comment: Hi, how do i get version 1.5.8 from the said string using a pattern match? sorry about this it's new to me :(

Comment: Can't really understand your question. This string replaces "1.5.8" with "1.5.9". What do you mean by "get"?